# How to use file_get_contents on loop?

Tags: php, json, loops

I'm trying to use file_get_contents on loop, in order to fetch JSON string from an URL continuously (every second). And i need to store the result into a javascript variable.
Here was my approach, but i didn't get any result from this. My page showed me nothing but endless loading.

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(0);
    while(true)
    {
    $jsonContent=file_get_contents('http://megarkarsa.com/gpsjson.php');
    echo $jsonContent;
    sleep(10);
    }

?>
```

And here my javascript code.

```
setInterval(function(){
        var jsonUpdPostData = <?php echo $jsonContent; ?>;
}, 100);
```

What should i do to make it work? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: You will want to do this with JS and ajax not PHP.

Comment: @marsje the file_get_contents did well for my need, because I just need to fetch a simple string from the url, and store it into js variable. But if you said JS and ajax is more efficient than php, can you point me how to use it? Thank you.

Comment: Your PHP code is an infinite loop. The fact that you have `sleep(10)` only blocks the thread for 10 seconds, but it won't return anything. The ajax request waits for the PHP code to be done, which never happens. To make it work, remove the while loop and the sleep. The `setInterval` on the JS side should be enough

Comment: @Adrien Oh. So, no need a loop on the PHP side? And depend only on the setInterval JS side? But, would the `$jsonContent`'s value be updated along with the setInterval?

Comment: Oh my bad, I misread your code. To achieve what you want, you need your PHP code to just have `echo file_get_contents('http://megarkarsa.com/gpsjson.php');`. Then in your JS code, you can make an ajax request to your server, that will return the new content

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work this way:

**getContent.php**

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('http://megarkarsa.com/gpsjson.php');
```

**xxxx.js**

```
setInterval(function(){
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
      alert(xmlhttp.responseText); // this contains the new file contents
    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open('GET', 'getContent.php');
  xmlhttp.send();
}, 100);
```